# How to create a login form in VB 2010 Ultimate

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need help in my login form using Access 2010.
This is my coding practice and there is an error in it!

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public Class Form1
Dim objCon As New OdbcConnection
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strConnection As String = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\HotelReservation\Practise\Login1.accdb"
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim attempt As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click


    If (txtUsername.Text = "") And (txtPassword.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please input username and password!")

    ElseIf (txtUsername.Text = "") Then

        MsgBox("Please input your Username!")
    ElseIf (txtPassword.Text = "") Then

        MsgBox("Please input your Password!")
    Else
        txtUsername.Text = strSQL
        txtPassword.Text = strSQL

        If (txtUsername.Text = strSQL) And (txtPassword.Text = strSQL) Then
            Form2.Show()
        End If
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the problem? It would be better if you mention the error you are getting? No one wants to check each line and guess the error.

Comment: What help, please specify, jeff. There must be an error message which you may be getting? Share that.

Comment: Assuming you've defined strSQL elsewhere from a connection to the server there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code. As Error 404 has asked, what is the error? Also - "vb 2010 ultimate" is completely unnecessary. Your IDE has no bearing on the coding problem you're having and you don't need to mention VB as that is what the tag is for.

Comment: strSQL = "Select * from tblUser adm_username = '" & txtUsername.Text & "' Admin adm_password= '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"

Comment: Ok, you still haven't identified the failure though. Are you receiving an error? Is Form2 just not showing?Also, Is there something else you have not included? I see no where in here that you actually use any of those connection declarations.

Comment: What will be the Connection Declaration on this

Comment: Yes there is an error on Connection declarations

Comment: @jeff please stop beating around the bush and state the error, we are not mind readers and are not staring over your shoulder.

Comment: Why are you setting both textboxes to strSQL and THEN checking if they both equal strSQL? Because of course that if statement is going to succeed--and surely not behave the way you want

Comment: step away from the computer and get yourself a good book or two on VB and programming in general.

Comment: Unless the Access file itself is protected, encrypted or otherwise unavailable to the user of the system, they could just open it up to read the usernames and passwords. You need a better and safer solution than this! Access just is not that solution!

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    ' Check if username or password is empty
    If txtPassword.Text = "" Or txtUsername.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error",        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        ' Both fields was supply
        ' Check if user exist in database
        ' Connect to DB
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
'your connection string
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data    Source=C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\HotelReservation\Practise\Login1.accdb"
         Try
            'conn.Open()
            'MsgBox("Susscess")
'your query
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

            'Open Database Connection
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlRead.Read() Then
                frmMainForm.Show()
                Me.Hide()

            Else
                ' If user enter wrong username and password combination
                ' Throw an error message
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                'Clear all fields
                txtPassword.Text = ""
                txtUsername.Text = ""

                'Focus on Username field
                txtUsername.Focus()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database..", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I need help on Connection Declaration on this

Comment: Ohh @StartCoding, when you give someone who struggles with Databases a code sample, please make it a safe one. This one if completely open to SQL injection!

Comment: @StartCoding A good example also explains what you did and why you did it. Just pasting in 20 lines of code doesn't really enlighten anyone.